# com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.InternCache.intern() deadlock under high load

Tags: java, jackson, tomcat7, deadlock

**Env:**

- Amazon
- Centos
- Apache-tomcat-7.0.53
- Java 8
- Jackson-core-2.2.3

**Problem**

When we test our servers with a  load of ~7000CCU, we see several of the following when we profile our appservers using Yourkit.

```
http-apr-8080-exec-952 <--- Frozen for at least 17 sec
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.InternCache.intern(String) InternCache.java:43
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.sym.CharsToNameCanonicalizer.findSymbol(char[], int, int, int) CharsToNameCanonicalizer.java:506
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._parseFieldName(int) ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1182
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken() ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:602
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase.nextValue() ParserMinimalBase.java:128
```

What can we do to improve the performance of this library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason, we were not closing the parser instance. By closing the parser instance in 'finally block' this issue has vanished.

Comment: Yes, this is commonly an indication of such a leak -- it is only in such cases that this should become a bottleneck. FWIW, later versions do try to handle this slightly more gracefully, but fundamentally not closing the parser will add other kinds of overhead so you really do want to ensure closing.

Comment: Did you try 
        val jf = new JsonFactory();
        jf.configure(JsonFactory.Feature.INTERN_FIELD_NAMES, false);
        jf.configure(JsonFactory.Feature.CANONICALIZE_FIELD_NAMES, false);